# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error when setting up HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, https, apache, redirection

I have a simple website running Magento CE 1.9 on a single `Linux/Apache` server.
The website works ok with HTTP but I am having a lot of issues trying to get HTTPS working.

After setting the Unsecure and `Secure Base URLS` to `https://` and saving the config, I immediately get logged out of the Admin console and get a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error. I have looked at and tried other similar posts people have made but nothing seems to fix it.

Current Magento settings:

`AUTO REDIRCECT TO BASE URL = NO`

`USE WEB SERVER REWRITES = YES`

`USE SECURE URLS IN FRONTEND = YES`

`USE SECURE URLS IN ADMIN = YES`

`OFFLOADER HEADER = SSL OFFLOADED`

I am not an experienced Magento or Web guy, so appreciate any guidance.

Thanks

Comment: What did you setup your full url? You may have forgotten this sign `/` at the end.

Comment: Have you checked using `curl` on the command line to make sure it's not just a browser cached redirect? `curl -I https://www.nicks-website.com/` Check for a 302 or a 200.

Comment: Thanks Danny I ran two checks and both returned 302. I cleared all browser cache and magento cache and session logs also. Problem still persists

Comment: Hi Adarsh, yes I used a `/` at end of each url. Can confirm  `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` both equal `https://nicks-website.com/`

Comment: Also for reference, this is what my HTACCESS file looks like. `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Just to close this out, a good friend of mine suggested I try this , and I am very pleased to say it worked. Perhaps it will help someone else who faces the same issue:  In .htaccess file:  `# Detect the ELB header and set the header magento expects`
`SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on`

Answer (score 6):

Just to close this out, a good friend of mine suggested I try this, and I am very pleased to say it worked. Perhaps it will help someone else who faces the same issue: In .htaccess file, add these lines:

`# Detect the ELB header and set the header magento expects
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on`

Comment: this solved my problem with magento 2 while using content delivery network.

Comment: Also the solution for moving Magento into a docker container.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check if your https is properly configured, eg. here https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
2. Clean Magento cache.
3. Clean your browser cache and Magento domain cookies. Try it on "private" browsing mode.
4. Create test.php file in your main Magento directory.

> <?php phpinfo();

Run https://[domain]/test.php and Ctrl+f for "HTTPS". Sometimes your server is hidden behind load balancer and there is no $_SERVER['HTTPS'] system variable. The fastest workaround is to add this line on the top of your index.php file:

> $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

Answer (score 0):

You could try: Backup your database and run the installation of your Magento 1.9.x.x again (use the exact same version to avoid bugs). 
Fill in both url's (non-secure and secure) with the https:// link. Now all links in your installation will be changed to https.

Or: 
You could also export your database with Phpmyadmin (note: "disable foreign keycheck" in phpmyadmin), change all http:// to https://, and import again (note: "disable foreign keycheck" again in phpmyadmin).

And clear your browser cache.

If it doesn't work, check your installation with the default .htaccess file to check wether there are redirect errors in it.

Answer (score 0):

The below command works for me.
I have nginx ingress controller in the front and apache-magento container in the backend. Just set it in the .htaccess of the magento root directory.

## Detect the ELB header and set the header magento expects

SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on