# "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" when turn on Cloudflare CDN possible .htaccess file issue

Tags: magento2, redirect, htaccess, .htaccess, apache

When I tried to turn on Cloudflare CDN, my site will get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error page (the site loads fine if I don't turn on Cloudflare CDN). I checked with the hosting provider, seems like the all the DNS are set correctly. They suspected that might be something in the .htaccess file causing redirect loops.

I'm not sure which line might cause the redirect loop, but I'm thinking it might be one of these lines. can someone help?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l  
RewriteRule .* index.php [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$  
RewriteRule ^track\/login\.php$ "http\:\/\/old\.mysite\.com\/track\/login\.php" [R=301,L]
```

Here is the complete .htaccess file

```
############################################
## overrides deployment configuration mode value
## use command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes

#   SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 756M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
############################################
## adjust memory limit

    php_value memory_limit 756M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
## disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
## disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json image/svg+xml

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!don't-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

############################################
## workaround for Apache 2.4.6 CentOS build when working via ProxyPassMatch with HHVM (or any other)
## Please, set it on virtual host configuration level

##    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
############################################

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
##redirect to homepage

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>

############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>

###########################################
## Deny access to root files to hide sensitive application information
    RedirectMatch 403 /\.git

    <Files composer.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files composer.lock>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .gitignore>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .htaccess.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .php_cs.dist>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files .travis.yml>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files CHANGELOG.md>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files COPYING.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files Gruntfile.js>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files LICENSE_AFL.txt>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files nginx.conf.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files package.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files php.ini.sample>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files README.md>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files auth.json>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>
    <Files magento_umask>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            order allow,deny
            deny from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
    </Files>

# For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response
ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /pub/errors/404.php

################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

# ######################################################################
# # INTERNET EXPLORER                                                  #
# ######################################################################

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Document modes                                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Force Internet Explorer 8/9/10 to render pages in the highest mode
# available in the various cases when it may not.
#
# https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#ie8
#
# (!) Starting with Internet Explorer 11, document modes are deprecated.
# If your business still relies on older web apps and services that were
# designed for older versions of Internet Explorer, you might want to
# consider enabling `Enterprise Mode` throughout your company.
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625.aspx#docmode
# http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
    # the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
    # HTML documents and not for the other resources.

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^track\/login\.php$ "http\:\/\/old\.mysite\.com\/track\/login\.php" [R=301,L]

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php71” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php71 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/182783/69 may help if you are using SSL negation to a load balancer.

Comment: The last answer adding "SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on" to .htaccess file solve the issue. Please post that as answer i'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: which server are you using? Apache or Nginx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/182783/69

> Just to close this out, a good friend of mine suggested I try this,
>   and I am very pleased to say it worked. Perhaps it will help someone
>   else who faces the same issue: In .htaccess file, add these lines:
>
> ```
> # Detect the ELB header and set the header magento expects
> SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of redirect loops is due to a combination of

1. a redirect performed by your origin web server, and
2. a Cloudflare SSL option that is incompatible with the redirect performed by your origin.

**Cause**

The Flexible **SSL** option within the Cloudflare **SSL/TLS** app encrypts traffic between the browser and the Cloudflare network over HTTPS. However, when the Flexible **SSL** option is enabled, Cloudflare sends requests to your origin web server unencrypted over HTTP. Redirect loops occur if your origin web server is configured to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS when using the Flexible **SSL** option.

Redirect loops may also occur when using the Full or Full(strict) **SSL** option.  The only difference is that Cloudflare contacts your origin web server over HTTPS and the redirect loop occurs if your origin web server redirects HTTPS requests to HTTP.

**Resolution**

Resolve redirect loops via one of the following methods:

1. (Recommended) Remove the HTTPS to HTTP or HTTP to HTTPS redirects from your origin web server configuration. For example:

   > a) Apache - [RewriteRules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000219871-Troubleshooting-redirect-loop-errors)
   >   b) nginx - [Rewrite directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) and [301 return directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return)
2. Update the **Cloudflare SSL** option in the **SSL/TLS** app:

   > a) Set to Flexible, update to Full if you have an **SSL certificate** configured at web server.
   >   b) (Not Recommended) If currently set to Full, update to Flexible.

Comment: thank you for the answer, both solutions should works, so i upvoted both, but i resolved using the other solution yesterday, so i picked that as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Not an Issue. Thank You such your precious Reply, If you any doubt then please let me know.